# Work around the need to override abstract methods in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract

I've been working on an assignment that involves an abstract class that represents a generic animal, with subclasses for cat, dog, reptile, etc. The superclass has abstract methods *that aren't actually used by each subclass.* For example, there are accessors and mutators for breed and gender that are used by dog and cat but not the reptile class. I personally think this is an odd setup, but it's what is required by the assignment.

At first I tried leaving out the abstract methods not used in a particular subclass, but I quickly found out that leads to an error, due to abstract methods not being overridden. All I had to do to fix that was put in the appropriate methods...

```
public class Reptile extends Animal
...
public void setBreed(String newBreed){}  
public String getBreed(){return null;}
```

...though it seems to be a bit of a waste seeing as they aren't used. It's not a huge issue, but it made me curious as to whether or not there is an alternative to having to override unused abstract methods in a given subclass. Barring that, is there any convention for what to do when you need to override an abstract method but won't actually be using the method at all?

Comment: Why not have a default implementation for some of the getters and setters?  Abstract classes don't need to have all methods be abstract.  (Though this might not apply to your specific case)

Comment: Depending on your usage, interfaces may be more appropriate. Since you're able to implement multiple interfaces to better define your class. Though I'm not sure that would be allowed for your assignment.

Comment: I can't have a default implementation because the assignment specifically requires that I use abstract for the methods that led to my post, though that or interfaces would be far more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions here.

You can have multiple levels of abstract classes. In other words (these are shell classes and functions...i.e. no code):

```
public abstract class Animal{
  public abstract void fooMethod();
}

public abstract class Pet extends Animal{
  public abstract void breed();
  public abstract void gender();
}

public class Reptile extends Animal{
  public void fooMethod(){}
}
public class Cat extends Pet{ //do the same for Dog
  public void fooMethod(){}
  public void breed(){}
  public void gender(){}
}
```

This way, Reptile still extends Animal, but you know Reptile doesn't have a breed or gender function, so you don't have to do anything for it. Similarly, Cat and Dog also extend Animal, but now they have breed and gender they must override as well.

Your other solution is to do something like this (the worse of the two solutions):

```
public class Reptile extends Animal{
  public void breed(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't call Reptile#breed!!");
  }
}
```

This solution is particularly bad, because if you don't have proper error handling, this exception will propagate all the way up the stack to your main method, and if there is not exception handling for this all the way to your main method, then your program crashes.

I recommend choice A, personally.

Comment: Good examples. Yet another option would be the use of interfaces.

Comment: in my particular example, yes, you could use interfaces. But if he has some functionality in Animal (such as fooMethod is not abstract), then he obviously couldn't.

Comment: Good point. Fortunately in most cases like this you have the option of restructuring your code to allow using interfaces. Especially with the excellent `default` implementations added in Java8

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer- I thought there might be some way of manipulating exception handling, but I agree that that isn't the best idea. Also, in this case, I wouldn't want further layers of abstraction, though I appreciate the explanation of how it would work. Do you know of any convention for having unused override methods, seeing as it looks like that's what I'll be doing in my assignment? (Unless my professor gets back to me and grants me some leeway!)

Comment: I suppose a third alternative would be just to have an empty function. Like "public void breed(){}", just so it won't do anything. Multiple levels of abstract classes isn't a bad thing. It may seem like overkill here, but in larger codebases, it will make your code much more manageable. Also, its much cleaner to do it this way, and is a generally accepted way to handle this in the Java community. It is a good idea to get in the habit of doing this now while you're still learning, and building habits; build the right habits now while you still can, instead of generating bad habits.

Comment: I do like the way that the extra class tidies things up, and I've no doubt that it can do good on larger projects. It's also good to know that's an accepted way of doing things. I realize I wasn't particularly clear in my post, but my current solution actually is having the empty functions, I'll edit it shortly. I have the 'get' methods return null- would you recommend something else? I also considered throwing an error when methods are called from a class that doesn't need them.

Comment: So what you just said is kind of a combination of what I said as my second solution and my third solution (in the comment above). I dont think you should really do either of those, but its really just preference as to why Im saying that; it is still a valid approach. Presumably you have some getBreed, and there you will just want to return null in the Reptile class for what you are saying. The errors you referenced is exactly my second solution, but has problems for the reasons I already mentioned. I still hold that you should try the first solution unless you have explicit reasons you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Another version of @earchengine's answer, add a couple of interfaces:

```
public abstract class Animal{
  public abstract void fooMethod();
}

public class Breed {...}
public interface Bred {
  Breed breed();
}

enum Gender { ...}

public interface Gendered
  Gender gender();
}

public class Reptile extends Animal {
  public void fooMethod(){}
}

public class Cat extends Animal implements Gendered, Bred {
  public void fooMethod(){}
  public Breed breed(){}
  public Gender gender(){}
}

public class Dog extends Animal implements Gendered, Bred {
  public void fooMethod(){}
  public Breed breed(){}
  public Gender gender(){}
}
```